# Run a function in new thread c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am working on application which calls a function populate() on window_load

This function execution takes about 1 minute to complete. I wanna make this function to be called in separate thread.

I am using following code

```
Thread thread = new Thread(PopulateAndDrawGraph);
        thread.Start();
```

in this function at last line is

nodeXlControl1.DrawGraph(true);

Here exception occurs

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

what wrong is actually occurs

Comment: ca you share the stack trace of that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used BackgroundWorker class in c#.

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowed to access UI controls from within the same thread that created the control, which is usally the UI thread itself.

You will need to change your code in a way that it becomes thread-aware.

Here is a fantastic article that was published in the MSDN magazine: [Give Your .NET-based Application a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx), which will explain in great detail how you can do what you want to do.

The article is a little old, but the same principles still apply.

I guess that the newer C# language features - like the new `async` / `await` keywords - should make your task a little easier.

But keep in mind that the same old limitations for accessing UI controls still exist. There is no way around to understand the basics as descripbed in the article.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to handle this, a correct way and another way:

1: If you want a good working solution then this should do the trick, ..

```
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
        // If these threads are different, it returns true. 
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

2: but if you want a quick solution without guarantee that it will work properly, just set this variable: 
[Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the any UI interaction has to occur in the main thread of the application. My advice is that you draw make the computation in the separate thread, but  collect your results in an object. After the thread is finished you can extract the result from that object, and place it the nodeXlControl1.

Sadly i don't know the details about your objective, the sum of the solution is this. 
If u can tell more details about this i may be able to further help you.

Answer (score 0):

check [this article (How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) here out. It explains all the related items regarding cross thread calls. I also recommend that you look into the concept of "Task" in c#. Theres a very well written lib that helps you handle parallelism and similar concepts!

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. I know you've linked to the MSDN, but changes happen and if the link goes bad this answer will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access a UI element from a thread you need to call `Invoke`. So in `PopulateAndDrawGraph` you should have:

```
Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    nodeXlControl1.DrawGraph(true);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the UI controls from any other thread except the thread which has created this control(you can access/change the UI control properties from the main UI thread only). Go through this link, i hope this makes you clear [Cross-thread operation not valid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/507f5d4b-d33e-40e0-8802-05fe46519658/)